# Need Postgres query result in given timezone

Tags: postgresql

I save all columns in UST. But I need to get all results in a particular timezone. I am using postgres.

I am looking for something like following

```
SELECT reported_time IN timezone 'Asia/Kolkata' FROM allusers;
```

I need result in 'Asia/Kolkata' timezone for exporting to a csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided that `reported_time` is of type `timestamp with time zone` as it should, the answer is

```
SELECT reported_time AT TIME ZONE 'Asia/Kolkata' FROM allusers;
```

Comment: I need the result contain modified timezone info also. Currently, it returns without timezone info. Is there any way to achieve this

Comment: Are you looking for `SELECT utc_offset FROM pg_catalog.pg_timezone_names WHERE name = 'Asia/Kolkata'`?